# Clarifications on the Eversmoking Bottle 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The description for the item says that you activate the item by removing the stopper, where it pours out a 60 foot radius cloud. This cloud expands until it reaches a maximum radius of 120 feet, and the cloud persists until the bottle is closed. The bottle can only be closed if you speak its command word, and 10 minutes later, the smoke is gone.

My question is as follows:

- What is the shape of the cloud formed, cylindrical or spherical? This is for calculating the maximum height of the cloud.

Comment: Usually, it's better to ask one question per, well, question.

Comment: Your first question was a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138487/what-happens-when-a-very-fast-creature-opens-an-eversmoking-bottle-then-moves-f?rq=1), so I revised your question to focus on the second one since we try to keep posts to one question per post. Feel free to adjust as desired.

Comment: My apologies for the duplicate question. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the shape, its technically up to DM choice as the item doesn't specify. A cylinder might be easier to adjudicate; however, every spell effect in 5e I can find that creates a cloud (Fog Cloud, Stinking Cloud, Cloudkill, Incendiary Cloud) creates a sphere, and a sphere would most accurately match the description of "60 foot radius cloud"

Comment: I edited the question to remove the duplicate question, so I revised your answer to remove that bit too, feel free to revise further however you like.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov    Revisions look fine to me.  
  Just saw your put the duplicate link under the question (it was still collapsed under when I peaked).

Comment: I just added a comment to the question explaining what I did. As for your answer, you make a great observation that a cylinder is easier to adjudicate that a sphere. I *HATE* having to work with spheres and flying creatures, and often just use a cylinder even when it’s supposed to be a sphere.